# "at this time" 这个时候 or 这时候 maybe 这段时间

Tags: grammar

I learnt that when I want to say "at this time" I should use 这时候。In a video, I saw 这个时候。 I learnt when I want to use a noun I should use 时间 and measure the word for time is 段。 I am confused now. When I want to say "at this time" I should use :
这时候 or
这个时候 maybe
这段时间
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

这时, 这时候, 这个时候, 就在这时, 在这一瞬间, 此时此刻, etc. means "at this moment".

这段时间, 这段时间里，这个时期，这个期间，etc. means "during this period" or "in the time period".

In many cases, you must refer to the context to understand whether it is a moment or a period. For example (那时),

那时我们家里很穷. During that time my family was very poor. (when I was a boy).

那时我没有多想，赶紧往人多的地方跑。At that moment I could not think too much but ran toward the crowd.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

**这**时候 = **这个**时候 = "at this **(point of**) time".

这**段**时间 = "**in** this **period**"

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.